# update Gradle to 2.10 error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I' using Gradle 2.9 in my Android Studio Project.

And today I try to update Gradle to 2.10, but got an error :
[image: error information]

I follow the tip and change it to 2.2, but it doesn't work, 2.10 neither.

I use local gradle distribution not the wrapper, so I think this tip looks useless.

Comment: which versions of android studio and gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1, gradle plugin 1.3.0.

Comment: try to use gradle 2.4 or 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been marked as [bug](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-thinks-2-10-is-less-than-2-2-when-resolving-plugins/13434), which will be fixed in next Android Studio version (1.5.x).

Until then, temporary fix is adding following line in top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
...
}
```